SwiftUI Charts Position By and Selection Data Point
I am trying to setup a SwiftUI Chart where the user can tap anywhere on the chart and if they are close enough to a data point, it will select that data point. I have this working using chartXSelection and chartYSelection but the issue is that when I use the position(by) modifier like this
.position(by: .value("Data ID", "\(data.id)")

so that multiple data points of the same mark type are position side by side to prevent overlaps, I can no longer select all drawn marks in the chart when two marks have the same date (x value) and amount (y value).
I've tried everything I can think of and haven't been able to solve it. My current though was to stop using chartXSelection and chartYSelection and instead use chartOverlay with a proxy but I can't get that working reliably either.
This is an example of what I currently have
Chart {
    ForEach(myData, id: \.id) { log in
        BarMark(
            x: .value(
                "Date",
                log.date,
                unit: .date
            ),
            y: .value(
                "Amount",
                log.amount
            ),
            stacking: MarkStackingMethod.unstacked
        )
        .position(by: .value("DataID", "\(data.id)"))

    }
}
.chartOverlay { proxy in
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Rectangle().fill(.clear).contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                                .onChanged {
                                    value in
                                    let location = value.location
                                    if let chartFrame = proxy.plotFrame {
                                        let chartFrame = geometry[chartFrame]
                                        let chartLocation = CGPoint(x: location.x - chartFrame.minX, y: location.y - chartFrame.minY)
                                        let dataPoints: [Chart_Data_Source_Log] = viewModel.chartData.flatMap { $0.chartDataSource.chartData }

                                        // Find the bar containing the tap location
                                        if let selectedBar = findBarAtLocation(
                                            location: chartLocation,
                                            dataPoints: dataPoints,
                                            chartFrame: chartFrame,
                                            chartProxy: proxy
                                        ) {
                                            print(selectedBar)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                        )
                }
            }
        }

and this is the function I've been playing with
func findBarAtLocation(location: CGPoint, dataPoints: [Data_Log], chartFrame: CGRect, chartProxy: ChartProxy) -> Data_Log? {
    let barWidth = chartFrame.width / CGFloat(dataPoints.count)

    for dataPoint in dataPoints {

        guard let barCenterX = chartProxy.position(forX: dataPoint.date) else {
            continue
        }

        let barLeft = barCenterX - barWidth / 2
        let barRight = barCenterX + barWidth / 2

        guard location.x >= barLeft && location.x <= barRight else {
            continue
        }

        guard let barTopY = chartProxy.position(forY: dataPoint.amount) else {
            continue
        }

        let barHeight = chartFrame.height - barTopY

        if location.y >= barTopY && location.y <= barTopY + barHeight {
            return dataPoint
        }
    }
    return nil
}

I am not suggesting that this is the correct solution. I just don't know what else to try at this point.
If I go with my first solution of using chartXSelection and chartYSelection, I am looping through my data array to match with the closest date and amount values, but since two data points have the exact same date and amount (and I cannot offset the data in any way), it will always return the first match which means I can never select the other data point.
Would love a creative working solution to this issue. Thanks!

I did something similar to this in this post, where there were only 2 bars. I will generalise this to any number of bars.
Suppose we have such a struct to represent our data:
struct DataPoint: Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let x: String
    let y: Double
    let type: String
    var id: String { "\(x)-\(type)" }
    
    var description: String {
        "\(x)-\(type)-\(y)"
    }
}

The bars will be grouped by type.
We need two more helper variables, dataByX and typeOrder. These can be calculated in findBarAtLocation every time, or you can cache them in a @State.
let data = [/* your actual data goes here*/]

// dataByX is a [String: [DataPoint]]
// of course, if 'x' is a Date, and each bar represents a month, 
// you should group by the year and month components, so this'll be [DateComponents: [DataPoint]]
dataByX = Dictionary(grouping: data, by: \.x)

// typeOrder stores the order of the bars. SwiftUI Charts seems to order the bars by the order they appear in 'data'
var seenTypes: Set<String> = []
typeOrder = []
for point in data {
    if seenTypes.insert(point.type).inserted {
        typeOrder.append(point.type)
    }
}

Finally,
func findBarAtLocation(location: CGPoint, proxy: ChartProxy, geometry: GeometryProxy) -> DataPoint? {
    guard let frame = proxy.plotFrame, // use proxy.plotAreaFrame on iOS 16
          let x = proxy.value(atX: location.x - geometry[frame].origin.x, as: String.self),
          let xRange = proxy.positionRange(forX: x),
          let bars = dataByX[x] else { return nil }
    let xInPlotFrame = location.x - geometry[frame].origin.x
    let groupWidth = xRange.upperBound - xRange.lowerBound
    let barWidth = groupWidth / CGFloat(typeOrder.count)
    for (i, type) in typeOrder.enumerated() {
        let barStartX = xRange.lowerBound + CGFloat(i) * barWidth
        let barRange = barStartX..<(barStartX + barWidth)
        if barRange.contains(xInPlotFrame) {
            // checking the y position of the touch location
            // has been left as an excerise for the reader
            return bars.first(where: { $0.type == type })
        }
    }
    return nil
}


A full example:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var dataByX: [String: [DataPoint]] = [:]
    @State var typeOrder: [String] = []
    @State var selection: DataPoint?
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(selection?.description ?? "nil")
        Chart(data) { point in
            BarMark(
                x: .value("X", point.x),
                y: .value("Y", point.y),
                stacking: .unstacked
            )
            .position(by: .value("Type", point.type))
            .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Type", point.type))
        }
        .chartOverlay { cProxy in
            GeometryReader { gProxy in
                Rectangle().fill(.clear).contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0).onChanged { value in
                        selection = findBarAtLocation(location: value.location, proxy: cProxy, geometry: gProxy)
                    })
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            dataByX = Dictionary(grouping: data, by: \.x)
            var seenTypes: Set<String> = []
            typeOrder = []
            for point in data {
                if seenTypes.insert(point.type).inserted {
                    typeOrder.append(point.type)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func findBarAtLocation(location: CGPoint, proxy: ChartProxy, geometry: GeometryProxy) -> DataPoint? {
        guard let frame = proxy.plotFrame, // use proxy.plotAreaFrame on iOS 16
              let x = proxy.value(atX: location.x - geometry[frame].origin.x, as: String.self),
              let xRange = proxy.positionRange(forX: x),
              let bars = dataByX[x] else { return nil }
        let xInPlotFrame = location.x - geometry[frame].origin.x
        let groupWidth = xRange.upperBound - xRange.lowerBound
        let barWidth = groupWidth / CGFloat(typeOrder.count)
        for (i, type) in typeOrder.enumerated() {
            let barStartX = xRange.lowerBound + CGFloat(i) * barWidth
            let barRange = barStartX..<(barStartX + barWidth)
            if barRange.contains(xInPlotFrame) {
                // checking the y position of the touch location
                // has been left as an excerise for the reader
                return bars.first(where: { $0.type == type })
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

let data = [
    DataPoint(x: "A", y: 1, type: "1"),
    DataPoint(x: "A", y: 2, type: "2"),
    DataPoint(x: "A", y: 3, type: "3"),
    DataPoint(x: "B", y: 2, type: "3"),
    DataPoint(x: "B", y: 3, type: "2"),
    DataPoint(x: "B", y: 4, type: "1"),
    DataPoint(x: "C", y: 3, type: "1"),
    DataPoint(x: "C", y: 4, type: "2"),
    DataPoint(x: "C", y: 5, type: "3"),
]


Thank you for the response. I ended up solving it using chartXSelection and chartYSelection and adjusting the date components of each date behind the scenes so it's invisible to the user, but allows me to use the hypot to calculate the closest data point. Took me about a week to figure out the right solution but now I can select any data point perfectly.
